# How to run a single case in llvm unittest

Tags: llvm

I only know that run all cases in llvm unittest :

···
./bin/llvm-lit -sv ./llvm/test/Uni
···
or

```
ninja llvm-check-unit
```

But, how to run a single case in llvm unittest？

And, how to debug a single case?

Thanks~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~